# Extjs 4. Why tree panel is not draggable?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I tried almost everything to make my tree draggable, but it is not working. Here is a part of my tree definition:

```
var tree = Ext.define('Bingo.view.objectTree', {
    extend:'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias:'widget.objectTree',  
    enableDD: true, // does not make it draggable
    enableDrag:true, // also not working
    viewConfig: {enableDD : true, plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'}}, // no effect
```

So, what configurations are correct and necessary?

**EDIT**

Now, pieces of code look like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'ext-4.1.1a/examples/ux');
Ext.require([
   'Ext.data.*',
   'Ext.grid.*',
   'Ext.tree.*'
]);
Ext.application({
   name: 'Bingo', 
   appFolder: 'app', 
   launch: function() {
      Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        requires:['Bingo.view.objectTree','Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop'],
        enableDD: true, // also not working
        enableDrag:true,    
        ddGroup : 'myDDgroup',
        viewConfig: {enableDD : true, plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop', ddGroup : 'myDDgroup'}},
       // .....


    var tree = Ext.define('Bingo.view.objectTree', {
    extend:'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias:'widget.objectTree',
    requires:['Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop'],  
    enableDD: true, // does not make it draggable
    enableDrag:true, // also not working
    viewConfig: {enableDD : true, plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'}}, // no effect
```

So, now I'm just wondering, if it is even possible to make a draggable tree in `extjs`. It looks as if only "official" solutions are working for some reason.

**EDIT**

Well, based on this thread [Sencha forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152144-treePanel-viewConfig-corruption-of-class-definition), I guess it is a bug, which persists in extjs 4.1.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EXTJSIV-4302] treePanel viewConfig - corruption of class definition

**This issue has been fixed in the Extjs 4.2.0**

[Please refer the release notes](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/release-notes.html)